# Problems returning an object in C++

Tags: c++

I'm just starting out in C++ and I'm having problems with one part of my assignment:

```
class Something {
     public:
         Random& random(); // should access a data member of type Random
     private:
         Random test(int r, int c);
}

Random& Something::random() {
         return (Random&) test;
}
```

And now there's an error with "test" in the function definition of random(), because "the expression must be an lvalue" and I built the solution and the error message given says "'&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression "

I have to keep the function declaration the way it is, because it's listed that way in the specs.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `test` is a function

Comment: Are you trying to declare `test` as a member variable, or as a member function?

Comment: Not only that, even if you were to call `test` correctly, you are returning a reference to a temporary.  That can't lead to good things happening.

Comment: Which parts of your posted code are open to modification?

Comment: @AdamJames, it's supposed to be a member variable. @R Sahu, the declaration of "test" is open to modification, as is the definition of "random()"

Comment: @sg2018 If `test` is supposed to be a member variable, it isn't.  So is the code you posted the actual code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it's the actual code from my work, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said in a comment: "test" is supposed to be a member variable.

Then, you need to change your class to:

```
class Something {
     public:
         Random& random(); // should access a data member of type Random
     private:

         // Not this. This declares test to be member function.
         // Random test(int r, int c);

         // Use this. This declares test to be member variable.
         Random test;
}

Random& Something::random() {
         return test;
}
```